# Array values not correct when pushing in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to fill an array in typescript, the key part of this is that each object pushed to the array has a different date. I have tried logging the dates and they are printing correctly, but at the end of the method after the loop, I log the array and every object has the same date. Here is my method:

```
createEmptySchedule(): void {
    const date = this.schedule.dates.startDate;
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      const day = new ScheduleSummaryDay();
      day.date = date;
      day.totalEmployees = 0;
      day.totalInOffice = 0;
      day.totalRemote = 0;
      day.totalNotWorking = 0;
      this.array.push(day);
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
```

And in my example, the start date is `2021-09-13`, but at the end, in my app and if I log the array, all the dates are `2021-09-20`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Date is mutable - and you only create one date and assign it to multiple array items: see https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/01/07/javascript-dates-be-aware-of-mutability/#:~:text=It%20seems%20that%20much%20like,after%20it%20has%20been%20created.

Comment: date is a reference object. You only have one of them. `day.date = date;` doesn't copy the contents of date. It sets `day.date` to the objects reference

Comment: instead you should create a copy of your data **inside** the loop: e.g. `date = new Date(this.schedule.dates.startDate.getTime())`